# count distinct values in big long array (performance issue)

Tags: java, performance, hashset

I have this:

```
long hnds[] = new long[133784560]; // 133 million
```

Then I quickly fill the array (couple of ms) and then I somehow want to know the number of unique (i.e. distinct) values. Now, I don't even need this realtime, I just need to try out a couple of variations and see how many unique values each gives.

I tried e.g. this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
....
HashSet<Long> length = new HashSet<Long>(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(hnds)));
System.out.println("size: " + length.size());
```

and after waiting for half an hour it gives a heap space error (I have Xmx4000m).

I also tried initializing Long[] hnds instead of long[] hnds, but then the initial filling of the array takes forever. Or for example use a Set from the beginning when adding the values, but also then it takes forever. Is there any way to count the distinct values of a long[] array without waiting forever? I'd write it to a file if I have to, just some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best suggestion would be to use a library like fastutil (http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) and then use the custom unboxed hash set:

```
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.LongOpenHashSet;
System.out.println(new LongOpenHashSet(hnds).size());
```

(Also, by the way, if you can accept approximate answers, there are *much* more efficient algorithms you can try; see e.g. [this paper](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1810000/1807094/p41-kane.pdf?ip=216.239.45.75&id=1807094&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=13316E526565D483%2E13316E526565D483%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=743618536&CFTOKEN=17784761&__acm__=1452296835_adecb2b17343547a57c181fd50831d2b) for details.)

Comment: wooaah! I still needed to increase the memory a little bit, but it runs in a couple seconds! I can use this for other things as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just sort it and count.

```
 int sz = 133784560;
 Random randy = new Random();
 long[] longs = new long[sz];
 for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { longs[i] = randy.nextInt(10000000); }
 Arrays.sort(longs);
 long lastSeen = longs[0];
 long count = 0;
 for(int i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
   if(longs[i] != lastSeen) count++;
   lastSeen = longs[i];
 }
```

Takes about 15 seconds on my laptop.